# How to use getter methods inside template engines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i am doing hobby project using node js, pug js is my template engine now i am in a situation like i need to use sequelize get method inside pug,
when i included the corresponding code it runs there and i am getting required output in console but i am not able to get it in frontend

```
block content
    main
        h1.text_center Task Assigned for #{task_added[0].userName}
        if task_added
            table(border=1)
                tr
                    th tasks
                    th project
                    th start-date
                    th status
                    th action
                each task in task_added
                    tr
                        td #{task.task}
                #this is where i am having issue
                        td= task.getProject().then(project =>{projectName = project.project;console.log(projectName);})
                        td #{task.start_date}
                        if task.status == 0
                            td not-started
                        else if task.status == 1
                            td started on #{task.start_date}
                        else
                            td finished on #{task.completed_date}
                        if task.status == 0
                            td
                                form(method='POST', action=('/admin/start'))
                                    input(type='hidden' name='userId' value=(task.userID))
                                    input(type='hidden' name='taskId' value=(task.id))
                                    button(type="submit") start
                        else if task.status == 1
                            td
                                form(method='POST', action=('/admin/complete'))
                                    input(type='hidden' name='userId' value=(task.userID))
                                    input(type='hidden' name='taskId' value=(task.id))
                                    button(type="submit") complete
                        else
                            td Change-Status
                        td
                            a(href='/admin/details/' + task.id) details
```

Comment: That's not a getter method. That's a promise method, and the sequelize database call is asynchronous. Do that *before* passing data into your template engine!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't call server side functions in pug template directly.

Usally you pass the function into it. Example for express

```
res.render('pug-filename', {
  getProjectName: function () {
    return task.getProject().then(project => { projectName = project.project; })
  }
});
```

In your Pug file then:

```
td #{getProjectName()}
```

Comment: can we pass arrguments to it ?

Comment: also i think we can't make async  functions in pug template engine